# Find shortest point from two list in python using machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I have two list of values in python. I want to find the shortest distance between each points from list1.

```
list1 = [(10,15),(40,50),(10,60)]
list2 = [(12,17),(38,48),(12,63),(11,17),(10,59)]
```

I need to find list1 each point to the list2 shortest point.

For instance If I take the first value from list1,

(10,15) - This point is shortest point to (12,17) and (11,17) in the list2.

Similarly for the second value in the list1,
(40,50) - Shortest point is (38,48)

I want the below output for each point,

```
(10,15) - [(12,17),(11,17)]
(40,50) - [(38,48)]
(10,60) - [(10,59)]
```

I have tried euclidean distance matching algorithm but I am unable to proceed further.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you're planning to try bigger examples, you might want to consider my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is, store the Euclidean distances in a dictionary mapped with the points as keys:

```
list1 = [(10,15),(40,50),(10,60)]
list2 = [(12,17),(38,48),(12,63),(11,17),(10,59)]
dict1, dict2 = {}, {}
for i,j in list1:
    for k,l in list2:
        dist = ((i-k)**2 + (j-l)**2)**0.5
        dict1[(k,l)] = int(dist)           # should use round(dist) instead
    min_dist = min(dict1.values())
    points = [keys for keys, values in dict1.items() if values == min_dist]
    dict2[(i,j)] = points

for k in dict2:
    print(k,'-',dict2[k])
```

Output:

```
(10, 15) - [(12, 17), (11, 17)]
(40, 50) - [(38, 48)]
(10, 60) - [(10, 59)]
```

**Note**: `(10, 15) - [(12, 17), (11, 17)]` this should not be the case, there should only be one closest point, which is `(11,17)`, if you want the closest integers, you should consider `round` instead of just dropping the floating points.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a `Point` class to store your cords and add methods to calculate distance. It could be something like:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, cords):
        self.x, self.y = cords

    def diff(self, others):
        difference = []
        for other in others:
            difference.append(((self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2) ** 0.5)
        return [x for _,x in sorted(zip(difference,others))]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.x, self.y))
```

With these set, you can loop through list1 and get all the sorted results:

```
list1 = [(10,15),(40,50),(10,60)]
list2 = [(12,17),(38,48),(12,63),(11,17),(10,59)]

for i in list1:
    result = Point(i).diff([Point(j) for j in list2])
    print (i, result)

#
(10, 15)[(11, 17), (12, 17), (38, 48), (10, 59), (12, 63)]
(40, 50)[(38, 48), (12, 63), (10, 59), (12, 17), (11, 17)]
(10, 60)[(10, 59), (12, 63), (38, 48), (11, 17), (12, 17)]
```

Comment: you may want to be careful about operator **, probably did you want to write the square root (in which case **(1/2) or **0.5 )

Comment: I actually checked as well. 5 ** 1/2 gives 2.5 whereas 5**(1/2) gives 2.236...=sqrt(5)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are mentioning machine learning in the title:

This is complete overkill for such a small example, but here is a solution to get all nearest neighbors, using `scipy.spatial` which is a library you should probably learn about if you are interested in machine learning.

```
def all_nearest_neighbor(p, l, T=None):
    if T is None:
        T = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(l)
    shortest,_ = T.query(p)
    shortest = int(shortest)
    high = 2
    # get an upper bound of the number of tie
    while True:
        d,_ = T.query(p, k=high)
        longest = d[-1]
        longest = int(longest)
        if longest != shortest:
            break
        high *= 2
    # now finish the binary search in [high//2, high[
    low = high // 2
    while high - low > 1:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        d,_ = T.query(p, k=mid)
        longest = d[-1]
        longest = int(longest)
        if longest == shortest:
            low = mid
        else:
            high = mid
    # finally get the indices
    _,indices = T.query(p, k=range(1,low+1))
    return [l[i] for i in indices]
```

As @SayandipDutta already noticed to get your expected result, we have to use the *truncated* euclidean distance which is a bit weird. If this is not what you want, comment the three lines with `int(...)` above.

In action:

```
>>> for li in list1: print('{} - {}'.format(li, all_nn(li, list2)))                                                                                                                      
(10, 15) - [(11, 17), (12, 17)]
(40, 50) - [(38, 48)]
(10, 60) - [(10, 59)]
```

And some stress test with bigger lists:

```
>>> list1 = [(random.randrange(1000), random.randrange(1000)) for i in range(1000)]
>>> list2 = [(random.randrange(1000), random.randrange(1000)) for i in range(100000)]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> %time T = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(list2)
CPU times: user 68.7 ms, sys: 18.1 ms, total: 86.8 ms
Wall time: 85.9 ms
>>> %time Counter(len(all_nn(li, list2, T)) for li in list1)
CPU times: user 347 ms, sys: 1.9 ms, total: 349 ms
Wall time: 348 ms
Counter({1: 1150, 4: 82, 7: 2, 2: 516, 3: 230, 6: 3, 5: 16, 8: 1})
```

Most of the time, only one nearest neighbor but sometimes up to 8.

Computing all the distances (even without looking for the smallest one and so on) takes a lot more time:

```
>>> %time cd = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(list1, list2)                                                                                                                                
CPU times: user 982 ms, sys: 371 ms, total: 1.35 s
Wall time: 1.35 s
```

Also comparing to the accepted answer (I know it's not pretending to be optimized):

```
>>> def SayandipDutta(list1, list2):
    dict1, dict2 = {}, {}
    for i,j in list1:
        for k,l in list2:
            dist = ((i-k)**2 + (j-l)**2)**0.5
            dict1[(k,l)] = int(dist)           # should use round(dist) instead
        min_dist = min(dict1.values())
        points = [keys for keys, values in dict1.items() if values == min_dist]
        dict2[(i,j)] = points
    return dict2
>>> %time d = SayandipDutta(list1, list2)
CPU times: user 2min 20s, sys: 510 ms, total: 2min 20s
Wall time: 2min 21s
```